# Method is running in a different thread.

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am getting started in iOS and Objective C programming and am running into a problem where my code is not executed synchronously.

The following code is in my ViewController.m file.

```
[[self classInstance] instanceMethod];
//more code here executes at the same time as instanceMethod
```

My instanceMethod and code after that are executed at the same time but the code after relies on instanceMethod running. Initially I tried to put it in a separate thread and then run the code after once it was complete but it seems that no matter what instanceMethod is never waited for.

The only way I have been able to get it to work is by doing:

```
[[self classInstance] instanceMethod];
while(self.classInstance.instanceVariable == nil){
  // wait for other code to fill the variables I need 
  // do nothing
}
// execute remaining code
```

I tried below but it does not work as expected.

```
dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{
    [[self classInstance] instanceMethod]; 

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //other code here for once instanceMethod is completed.
    });    
});
```

I feel I am missing something basic that I don't understand yet.

Comment: What does this `instanceMethod` do? Show its code.

Comment: The code in the method was simplistic and just filled a variable to user defaults. The code directly after used user defaults but it wasn't waiting on it to be filled. I replaced the code with logging and noticed the same behavior. The question is about why does the classes instance method get dispatched to its own thread and how to ensure the following code executes after it is finished running. The code in the method is irrelevant to the question because any code replicates the behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a good solution to add completion block to the `instanceMethod`:

```
[[self classInstance] instanceMethodWithCompletion:^{
    // Handle finish of the instance method
}];
```

And declare `instanceMethod` like this:

```
- (void)instanceMethodWithCompletion:(void (^)(void))completion {
    // Do something...

    if(completion) {
        completion();
    }
}
```

It will allow the `instanceMethod` to tell that it has been finished and run any other code within the block.

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. Any idea why if I create a thread, and dispatch two blocks with dispatch_sync, they don't execute in order on that thread? Or perhaps you know a resource to demonstrate what exactly is happening?

Comment: I guess `instanceMethod` starts some asynchronous operation, doesn't it? That could be a reason of the issue.

Comment: To answer your question more exactly I need to see what `instanceMethod` does.